# SearchServiceStarter failed or timed out

Tags: android

Sometimes the AlarmManager does not sending the alarms.
So I checked the logs.

The adb shell dumpsys alarm says "Outstanding deliveries" of over 300 alarms.

I have just seen on my device that I get a lot of error messages every few seconds about a "SearchServiceStarter":

```
E/SearchServiceStarter: Task 174 failed or timed out. Client 75449983474519810 disconnecting from SearchService!
                                                     java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
                                                         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.ct(SourceFile:75)
                                                         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.get(SourceFile:57)
                                                         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.cg.n(SourceFile:2)
                                                         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.av.l(SourceFile:50)
                                                         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ax.run(SourceFile:5)
                                                         at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bc.run(SourceFile:2)
                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Does anyone know what service this is and why this is crashing/gettting a timed out? Seems this is prevent the alarm manager from sending the alarms.

If I reboot the phone it is working again for 4 - 6 hours until I get the same problem.

Running on Pixel with latest 7.1.2 May release.

**Update:**
Found the package name who throws this message. The GoogleSearchBox :-(
[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem! @chrisonline Did you ever find a way around it besides rebooting your device? That didn't seem to work for me. This also is apparently interfering with my bluetooth connection as well.

Comment: Sadly not. I have now tried to upgrade to Android O (8.0) and I get again the same error message but it seems it does not block the AlarmManager anymore ?!

Comment: I am having the same issue but in Bluetooth Low Energy

Comment: @chrisonline did you find out the solution i'm also facing same issue with BLE.

Comment: No, but it seems I don't get any reports anymore. Seems fixed itself?!